# How can I make my bot assign a role when a user joins the server, then take it off after two minutes?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to program a bot for my discord server, and now I want to make it assign a role (let’s call it `new`) when a user joins the server. After, when the user has been in the server for two minutes, I would like to make the bot take off the role `new`. I searched everywhere, but did not find an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple. First you need your bot to listen to the [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event. After that you'll need to do [`addRole`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole) to said member. 
Then you need to create a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) after which you call [`removeRoll`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=removeRole) on the member